# Generate JSON Schema from sample JSON data in C# with NJsonSchema

Tags: c#, json, njsonschema

I am hoping this is me not holding it right, but I am trying to generate a JSON schema from a JSON string that I have in memory.

I am using the NJsonSchema off of GitHub.  https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/

```
string json = @"{
  ""a"": 1,
  ""name"": ""Bill Smith"",
  ""isTall"": true
}";

var schemaItem = JsonSchema4.FromJson(json);
string jsonSchema = schemaItem.ToJson();
```

When I execute the code above I get the following value in jsonSchema which is not correct.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "a": 1,
  "name": "Bill Smith",
  "isTall": true
}
```

I have created a GitHub bug for it for the time being just in case.  https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/issues/180

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of [NJsonSchema](http://njsonschema.org) you can generate a JSON Schema from sample data:

**See https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/SampleJsonSchemaGenerator**

The commit: https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/commit/28d5a1357a9b5a3367154d3bc6e2488769b721aa

Will be available in version v7.6.

The DataToJsonSchemaGenerator: https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema/Generation/DataToJsonSchemaGenerator.cs

I think there's also a FromJsonData method on JsonSchema4....

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong, `JsonSchema4.FromJson(string json)` is used to load existing schema json, not loading arbitrary json and generating a schema from it.

What you might be looking for is `JsonSchema4.FromType<MyType>()` which can generate a schema from a type, though you would need to have actual types for everything then.

As far as I can tell there isn't any way to generate a schema from just json so you'll need to create a class that matches your input. If you need that then you can have a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema, though it is not a free solution (and I'm in no way affiliated with it).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately creating types for my json objects is not something I have the opportunity to do with the application for which I am using it.  I am looking to do exactly what this does: http://jsonschema.net/#/.  I have an object represented in JSON and I want the associated JSON Schema.  Also, It seems that JsonSchema4.FromUrl(validUrlWithJson) works how I would expect as well.  It takes the JSON from that URL and seems to create a schema from it.

Comment: Just had a look at the source for `JsonSchema4.FromUrl` and all it does it is fetch data from a url and then pass it to `JsonSchema4.FromJson` so it won't help you. I'm afraid that you might need to code this one yourself though it shouldn't be that hard to do since json just have a few types for you to handle (string, int, bool, possibly date).

Comment: Yeah thanks. I was hoping something would do it for me so I didn't have to run the risk of meaaibg up the schema from hand building it.